# Different camera settings for different render layers?

Tags: rendering

I have a scene with two objects.  I need one to be rendered with the camera set to Perspective and the other to be rendered with an Orthographic camera.

I've put them on separate render layers, but it seems there can only be a single camera for both render layers.  Is that true?

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use a different scene. (I think. I'll test in a second..)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have multiple cameras, but only one can be used at a time.

As a workaround, you can use two scenes.

1. Move the object to be rendered in Perspective to the first layer and the object to be rendered in Orthographic to the second layer.

   Go to the Layers tab and select Layer 1 to be rendered.

   [image: Select Layer 1]
2. Create a new scene by clicking the **+** in the *Info Panel*:

   [image]

   Select *Link Objects*.
3. In the new scene, select the camera and press <kbd>U</kbd>*> Object and Data* to make the camera's transforms and settings independent from the original scene.  Then set the camera to be orthographic in *Properties > Object data > Lens*.
4. Still in the new scene, go to the Layers tab and select Layer 2 to be rendered.
5. Set the background to transparent by enabling *Transparent* in *Render settings > Film*.
6. In the composite nodes (for either scene, just keep in mind that they are independent so it's easiest to keep all the nodes in one scene) duplicate the *Render Layers* node and pick the other scene:

   [image]
7. You can now combine them however you want using the compositor. E.g. with an Alpha Over node:

   [image: Suzanne in Orthographic and Cube in Perspective]

In this render, Suzanne is in orthographic and the rest is in perspective.

Comment: Good call, that's not too painful.  But I have some edits to suggest since I wanted just one object to be in Orthographic and the rest of the scene in Perspective.

Comment: It turned out to be more editing that I thought, but let me know what you think.

Comment: @Garry I adjusted it slightly (creating two renderlayers in each scene is unnecessary), but good job otherwise :)

Comment: nice, that simplifies thing.

Comment: Does this question need to be updated for 2.8?

Comment: @use877329 indeed, I'll see what I can do.