# How do you render a stereoscopic image?

Tags: rendering

I want to create a 3D animation, but by 3D I mean if you had a 3D tv/screen you could watch it in 3d. From my research in 3d video files they are just regular formats like .avi but they have 2 frames for every one frame of movement. To do this in blender I could put 2 cameras slightly spaced out from each other but how could I get them to both render a image for each frame? Can this be done in regular blender or do I need a plugg-in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use two scenes two render two cameras (see [Different camera settings for different render layers?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6277/599))

However, [this is a feature that is currently being developed](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Dfelinto/Stereoscopy), so you could try [one of the development versions](http://graphicall.org/?keywords=multiview).