# How do you switch to a completely different camera in a different Blender layer?

Tags: layers

Say I create another scene in a blank layer. How do I switch to that totally different scene during rendering?
Thanks guys!

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1067/599. Though instead of animating the visibility of all the objects on separate layers (you could do in it a few clicks, but it still is a bit clunky), you might want to try [using separate scenes](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6277/599) (or even separate files, with linked objects where necessary) and rendering the two scenes out separately, combining them later in the compositor.

Comment: What do you mean animating the visibility of all the objects on separate layers?  WHy is that clunky?  Does it work?  Perhaps you are right no matter what though in the sense that I should use difference files!

Comment: It would work, but instead of animating one property (the visibility of a layer (not supported), or the visibility of a scene strip in the VSE) you would have to animate the visibility per-object. There is a way to do it in a few clicks, the way i'm thinking of will interfere with other animations.